# How to rename de pdf file hosted with Google Drive with a Google App Script (Cannot find function setName in object error)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I'm trying to rename a .pdf file in a google drive folder with Google App Script.

```
function findFilesInFolder() {
    var childrenData = Drive.Children.list('XXXXXXX')
    var children = childrenData.items;

    //loops through the children and gets the name of each one
    for (var i = 0; i < children.length; i++){
      var id = children[i].id;
      var file = Drive.Files.get(id);
      file.setName('testname');
    }
  }
```

Looking at this doc https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#setName(String) `setName` is the right method to use.

Comment: For some reason your `file` is not valid.  Log the `id`  After this line: `var id = children[i].id;` Add:  `Logger.log('id: ' + id)`  Run the code, then from the View menu, choose Logs.  If there is no `id` or if there is no file with that `id` then the variable `file` may not be a valid file.

Comment: Log is working ok. I have some file id. Actually I've already log the title of each file and It's working. So I think the issue is somewhere else.

Comment: Are you using `setName` somewhere else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are confusing your file objects. Your code uses the [`Drive` "advanced service"](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/drive) to obtain [file **metadata**](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/files/get), and does not use the native "Drive Service" via [`DriveApp`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/) (an implementation of the Drive REST API that provides fewer features in exchange for being easier to use) to get a `File`-class object.

If you want to use the native `DriveApp#File#setName` method, then instead of using the `Drive` method `Drive.Files.get` use [`DriveApp.getFileById`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#getFileById(String)), once you have the relevant `id` value:

Changing the name via `DriveApp#setName`:

```
for (var i = 0; i < children.length; i++){
  var id = children[i].id;
  var file = DriveApp.getFileById(id);
  file.setName('testname');
}
```

Changing the name with `Drive` advanced service:

```
for (var i = 0; i < children.length; i++){
  var fileData = children[i];
  fileData.title = "testname";
  Drive.Files.patch(fileData, fileData.id);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the API's call. For an example [update](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/files/update).

```
Drive.Files.update({title: 'new title'}, id)
```

The next code should work fine for you.

```
function renameFiles_(title, newTitle) {
  return Drive.Files.list({
    q: Utilities.formatString("title='%s'", title)
  }).items.map(function(item) {
    return Drive.Files.update({
      title: this.newTitle
    }, item.id)
  }, {
    newTitle: newTitle
  });
}

function test(){
  Logger.log(renameFiles_("XXXXXXX", "testname"));
}
```